# Using a git repository as the base of a new project

Tags: git

If I want to use for example the [Electron Quick Start](https://github.com/atom/electron-quick-start) as the base of a new app, should I use a normal clone and just delete the `.git` folder, or is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use this repo as a template, to begin a new project, not expand on an existing product. You're not interested in history, only a snapshot starting point.

In that case, deleting the .git folder and starting over with a new `git init` would be the simplest solution, IMO.

Comment: I'm an engineer, this suggestion follows the engineer rule KISS :)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of doing a full `clone` only to delete the `.git` directory again, you can only retrieve the `archive` of the repository you want to start from.

```sh
$ mkdir new-project/
$ cd new-project/
$ git archive --remote="${giturl}" HEAD | tar -x
$ git init
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "Staring off with revision ${rev} of repository ${repo}."
```

See [`git help archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) for more information.

Comment: This answer is fine, but it should contain a note it works only in an environment where `tar` is available.

Comment: You can also use the download zip option that github and most git services provide.

Comment: You could also use clone but with "--depth 1" to prevent it pulling down all the history. You'd still need to delete the .git directory afterwards, but it would save you some time/bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the answer game, but I have found out about `git checkout --orphan` recently, and this seems like the perfect scenario.

Running `git checkout --orphan <branch_name>` allows you to start a new branch based on an existing branch, but there will be no commit history. It's like doing `git init` on a new project folder.

One good use-case is for deploying gh-pages and for repos that have a branch for the deployed site: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/its-for-the-orphans

Answer (score 0):

You can fork the repository in github and rename the forked repository something more appropriate for your application.

Alternatively you could clone the repository, and change the origin remote to the repository of your application or add your repository as a new remote.

Comment: If you fork or clone you (normally) keep the history. That may not be what the OP wants if he just wants to use a random project as a start template.